# AWS CDK Pipeline - action before synth

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a standard CDK pipeline and use the output of `mvn package` to build a docker container. This one is used as DockerImageAsset and gets deployed to different environments. Therefore, the `mvn package` must run before the `cdk synth`.

While this works, I don't like the fact that the `mvn package` runs within the Synth action and I would prefer to have a separate action before, that also publishes test results from unit tests etc.

Is there a way to get an action before Synth ?

This is the current code:

```
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
    dockerEnabledForSynth: true,
    dockerEnabledForSelfMutation: true,
    crossAccountKeys: true,
    synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
        input: CodePipelineSource.gitHub('OWNER/repo', 'main', {
            authentication: SecretValue.secretsManager('GITHUB_TOKEN'),
        }),
        commands: [
            './mvnw package',
            'npm ci',
            'npm run build',
            'npx cdk synth',
        ]
    })
});

...

const dockerImage = new DockerImageAsset(this, 'Image', {
    directory: '......'
});

...
```

Comment: Its a code pipeline - is there are particular reason you cannot just  add another stage? that then outputs whatever maven artifacts are needed?

Answer (score 1):

There is [another CDK construct library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-codepipeline-readme.html) for AWS CodePipeline that is lower-level and unopinionated, which should allow you to add stages before the synth stage.

There is also a method [`buildPipeline`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.CodePipeline.html#buildwbrpipeline) for the higher-level pipeline construct you are currently using (the `CodePipeline` construct) that allows you to build the lower-level pipeline (the `Pipeline` construct). Note that once you call this method you can't modify the higher-level construct anymore. After building the lower-level pipeline construct, you might be able to call `addStage` on it and pass in the [`placement`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline.StageOptions.html#placement) property to add the stage prior to the synth stage, like so:

```
pipeline.buildPipeline()
const builtPipeline = pipeline.pipeline
builtPipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Maven',
  placement: {
    rightBefore: pipeline.stages[1]
  }
})
```

I have not personally tried this method so I cannot guarantee it, but if that doesn't work, then converting the CDK code to the lower-level construct library and using that from the beginning should work. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/pipelines-readme.html) for the higher-level construct library:

> CDK Pipelines is an *opinionated construct library*....If you want or need more control, we recommend you drop down to using the `aws-codepipeline` construct library directly.